# Почему не работает анимация UIActivityIndicatorView после fade перехода

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Расширил `UINavigationController`, функцией перехода с использованием `CATransition`.

```
func pushViewControllerWithFadeTransition(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    let transition = fadeTransition()
    view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)

}

func fadeTransition() -> CATransition {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade
    return transition
}
```

При попытке запушить контроллер-заглушку с `UIActivityIndicatorView` в центре, переход проходит правильно, но индикатор замирает, причем, во время анимации перехода видно, что индикатор анимирован, но при окончании перехода останавливается.

Подскажите, как сделать корректный переход, чтобы анимация работала корректно? `startAnimation()` и `behavior animating` включено/пробовал

**UPD**
Оборачивание в `CATransaction.begin() / .commit()` не дало результата.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вручную стартовать `UIActivityIndicatorView` в

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```